# Delete and replace the last character printed to the terminal in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, character, raspberry-pi2

I have this code that reads 16 analog analog sensors connected though multiplexer and ADC to my GPIOs and converts everything to a character accordingly and writes in to my terminal side by side each character, how can I delete and replace just the last printed character?
Now it just covers the last printed character and print right next to it the new. The purpose of this project is to create an oldschool sms texter emulator.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import spidev # import the SPI driver
from time import sleep
from array import *
DEBUG = False
vref = 3.3 * 1000 # V-Ref in mV (Vref = VDD for the MCP3002)
resolution = 2**10 # for 10 bits of resolution
calibration = 38 # in mV, to make up for the precision of the components
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
start_time=time.time()
elapsed_time=time.time()
keypressed=0
i=0
keyreleased = False
sensor16=['1','-','\\','/','*','!']
sensor15=['4','G','H','I']
sensor14=['7','P','Q','R','S']
sensor13=['*']
sensor12=['2','A','B','C']
sensor11=['5','J','K','L']
sensor10=['8','T','U','V']
sensor09=['0',' ']
sensor08=['3','D','E','F']
sensor07=['6','M','N','O']
sensor06=['9','W','X','Y','Z']
sensor05=['#']
sensor04=['BACKSPACE']
sensor03=['DELETE ALL']
sensor02=['READ']
sensor01=['TRANSMITE']
sensor=[sensor01,sensor02,sensor03,sensor04,sensor05,sensor06,sensor07,sensor08,sensor09,sensor10,sensor11,sensor12,sensor13,sensor14,sensor15,sensor16]
max_press=[1,1,1,1,1,5,4,4,2,4,4,4,1,5,4,6]
num_press=0
steps=0

# MCP3002 Control bits
#
#   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
#   X   1   S   O   M   X   X   X
#
# bit 6 = Start Bit
# S = SGL or \DIFF SGL = 1 = Single Channel, 0 = \DIFF is pseudo         differential
# O = ODD or \SIGN
# in Single Ended Mode (SGL = 1)
#   ODD 0 = CH0 = + GND = - (read CH0)
#       1 = CH1 = + GND = - (read CH1)
# in Pseudo Diff Mode (SGL = 0)
#   ODD 0 = CH0 = IN+, CH1 = IN-
#       1 = CH0 = IN-, CH1 = IN+
#
# M = MSBF
# MSBF = 1 = LSB first format
#        0 = MSB first format
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#events = (uinput.KEY_X, uinput.KEY_H, uinput.KEY_E, uinput.KEY_L, uinput.KEY_O)
#device = uinput.Device(events)

# SPI setup
spi_max_speed = 1000000 # 1 MHz (1.2MHz = max for 2V7 ref/supply)
# reason is that the ADC input cap needs time to get charged to the input level.
CE = 0 # CE0 | CE1, selection of the SPI device
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,CE) # Open up the communication to the device
spi.max_speed_hz = spi_max_speed

#
# create a function that sets the configuration parameters and gets the results
# from the MCP3002
#
#events = (uinput.KEY_X, uinput.KEY_H, uinput.KEY_E, uinput.KEY_L, uinput.KEY_O)
#device = uinput.Device(events)

def read_mcp3002(channel):
    # see datasheet for more information
    # 8 bit control :
    # X, Strt, SGL|!DIFF, ODD|!SIGN, MSBF, X, X, X
    # 0, 1,    1=SGL,     0 = CH0  , 0   , 0, 0, 0 = 96d
    # 0, 1,    1=SGL,     1 = CH1  , 0   , 0, 0, 0 = 112d
    if channel == 0:
        cmd = 0b01100000
    else:
        cmd = 0b01110000

    if DEBUG : print("cmd = ", cmd)

    spi_data = spi.xfer2([cmd,0]) # send hi_byte, low_byte; receive hi_byte, low_byte

    if DEBUG : print("Raw ADC (hi-byte, low_byte) = {}".format(spi_data))

    # receive data range: 000..3FF (10 bits)
    # MSB first: (set control bit in cmd for LSB first)
    # spidata[0] =  X,  X,  X,  X,  X,  0, B9, B8
    # spidata[1] = B7, B6, B5, B4, B3, B2, B1, B0
    # LSB: mask all but B9 & B8, shift to left and add to the MSB
    adc_data = ((spi_data[0] & 3) << 8) + spi_data[1]
    return adc_data


try:
    while True:
        for x in range(0, 16):  # setting the 4 channels of the multiplexer HIGH or LOW accordinlgy
            if x == 0:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 1:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 2:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 3:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 4:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 5:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 6:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 7:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 0)
            elif x == 8:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)
            elif x == 9:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)
            elif x == 10:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)
            elif x == 11:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 0)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)
            elif x == 12:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)
            elif x == 13:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 0)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)
            elif x == 14:
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)
            elif x == 15:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(11, 1)
                GPIO.output(13, 1)
                GPIO.output(15, 1)      
            # average three readings to get a more stable one
            channeldata_1 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
            sleep(0.001)
            channeldata_2 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
            sleep(0.001)
            channeldata_3 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
            channeldata = (channeldata_1+channeldata_2+channeldata_3)/3
            #
            # Voltage = (CHX data * (V-ref [= 3300 mV] * 2 [= 1:2 input divider]) / 1024 [= 10bit resolution]
            #
            voltage = int(round(((channeldata * vref * 2) / resolution),0))+ calibration
            if DEBUG : print("Data (bin)    {0:010b}".format(channeldata))
            if x==15 :      # some problem with this sensor so i had to go and twicked the thresshold
                voltage = voltage - 500
            #time.sleep(0.05)
            if ( voltage > 2500) :   #key is released
                keyreleased = True
            if ( voltage < 2500) :   #key is pressed
                keyreleased=False
                keypressed=x         #define which key is pressed
               # print(i)
                if key == keypressed :
                    while keyreleased == False :

                    #for i in range (max_press[keypressed]):
                        # average three readings to get a more stable one
                        channeldata_1 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
                        sleep(0.001)
                        channeldata_2 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
                        sleep(0.001)
                        channeldata_3 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
                        channeldata = (channeldata_1+channeldata_2+channeldata_3)/3
                        #
                        # Voltage = (CHX data * (V-ref [= 3300 mV] * 2 [= 1:2 input divider]) / 1024 [= 10bit resolution]
                        #
                        voltage = int(round(((channeldata * vref * 2) / resolution),0))+ calibration
                        if DEBUG : print("Data (bin)    {0:010b}".format(channeldata))
                        if x==15 :         # some problem with this sensor so i had to go and twicked the thresshold
                            voltage = voltage - 500
                        #time.sleep(0.05)
                        if ( voltage > 2500) :     #key is released
                            keyreleased = True
                            i=0
                        if i < max_press[keypressed] and keyreleased == False :
                        ########################################################
                        #this is where my characters are printed but i need to #
                        #print them side by side and to delete just the last   #
                        #character if i have to !!!!!!!!!!!                    #
                        ########################################################
                            print("\b", sensor[keypressed][i], end="", flush=True)
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            i=i+1
                        else :
                            i=0
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
            key = keypressed
            start_time=time.time()
        if DEBUG : print("-----------------")


except KeyboardInterrupt: # Ctrl-C
    if DEBUG : print ("Closing SPI channel")
    spi.close()

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any idea how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most terminals move the caret backwards once when the backspace character (ASCII 0x08) is printed:

```
sys.stdout.write('...');  # print "..."
time.sleep(1);  # wait a second
sys.stdout.write('\010\010\010Done.\n') # replace "..." with "Done."
```

To remove text simply move backward with the backspace character and then write spaces.

Alternatively, on most terminals:

```
sys.stdout.write('...');  # print "..."
time.sleep(1);  # wait a second
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')  # erase line and go to beginning of line
sys.stdout.write('Done.\n') # print "Done."
```

You can use any of the following ANSI escape sequences on terminals that support them (which is most modern terminals):

- `'\033[#D'`: Move cursor left by `#` characters.
- `'\033[2K'`: Clear current line (but don't move cursor).
- `'\033[1K'`: Clear line to the left of current position.
- `'\033[0K'`: Clear line to the right of current position.
- `'\033[1G'`: Move cursor to beginning of line.
- `'\033[#;#f'`: Move cursor to specific position. First `#` is row number, second `#` is column number.

Wikipedia as a convenient summary of [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).